# redirect and masking a domain on a restful api

Tags: node.js, api, express, dns, url-masking

so I'm very new to node.js and back-end.
I've just deployed a restful api on AWS just as a little test, it really does nothing special, only some get-post requests updating a json.
It works as expected.

Problem is: the address is of course very long so i also wanted to redirect the requests from a domain easy to remember.
And so i did.
If the domain is unmasked, it works fine, and i can for example get a json:
apiunmasked.pileoni.site/all
Settings on namecheap:
[image]

If i do try to mask it, it still works but the browser don't format it as a json:
api.pileoni.site/all.
[image]

Also there is something weird in the marging that happen with the masked version on the main page:
api.pileoni.site
apiunmasked.pileoni.site

I guess is some wrong setting on namecheap?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct request to the EC2 do not adds the **Content-Type** header in HTTP response, so the browser tries to guess the datatype and correctly recognize and manages it as JSON.
The Namecheap forward service adds the header, probably falling back to "text/html", and the browser display the content as HTML.

Eventually, try to enforce the **Content-Type** header to "application/json" in your Node application with [setHeader()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value).